# Quais as diferenças entre Flask e Django?

Tags: python, django, flask

Comecei a pouco tempo na linguagem Python e atualmente estou trabalhando em um projeto utilizando `Flask`, `MariaDB` e `WebSockets`.

Vejo as pessoas falarem muito sobre `Django` e gostaria de saber as diferenças entre dois.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Para quem já está trabalhando com um framework, fica relativamente fácil entender, o Flask é um micro-framework enquanto o Django é um framework Fullstack.

Um framework fullstack como o Django já vem "de fábrica" com todas as ferramentas essenciais para o desenvolvimento backend, enquanto um micro-framework como o Flask vem apenas com o mínimo necessário para o inicio de desenvolvimento e requer plugins para as ferramentas conforme demanda.

Para desenvolvimento de uma aplicação web em Python, geralmente é necessário:

- Linguagem de templates
- Gerenciamento de sessão
- Manipulação de formulários
- Manipulação de bancos de dados relacionais via ORM
- Serviços de autenticação de usuários;
- Configuração e manipulação de URLs (Rotas)
- Tratamento e manipulação de requisições/respostas HTTP

Em um framework fullstack como o Django, todas essas funções vem "embutidas" como pacotes, enquanto em um microframework como o Flask, é preciso ir conectando plugins para isso.

Mesmo entre os micro-frameworks ha diferenças entre as escolhas para essas ferramentas, por exemplo enquanto o Flask escolheu o [Jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/) para o mecanismo de templates, o [Bottle](https://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/) tem um mecanismo próprio "built-in", porém suporta [mako](http://www.makotemplates.org/), [jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/) e [cheetah](http://www.cheetahtemplate.org/).

### Qual é melhor?

Nenhum! :-) No mainstream existe uma clara tendencia de valorizar mais os framework Fullstack em detrimento dos micro-frameworks, parece óbvio, "se o fullstack já vem com todas as baterias, porque escolher um micro?" mas isso pode ser um equivoco. As duas opções tem suas vantagens e suas desvantagens. Enquanto em um fullstack você pode ter a sensação de que tudo está a mão, no micro você tem a sensação de liberdade, porém enquanto no micro você pode ter a sensação de que está faltando algo, no full você pode ter a sensação de estar aprisionado.

Agora falando da minha experiencia pessoal, tive um breve período com o Flask e agora estou envolvido com o Django e já pude perceber uma detalhe crucial que vai me fazer voltar para o Flask em um projeto específico. Para lidar com banco de dados legado, é muito mais fácil com o Flask do que com o Django, em função de seus ORMs, apesar de o Django suportar também o mesmo ORM ([SQLAlchemy](https://www.sqlalchemy.org/)) do Flask.